# conditional creation of policy in aws_iam_policy_document resource with dynamic block throws an error

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

What I want to achieve is to create aws policy based on a boolean values (`s3_logging_enabled` and `elb_logging_enabled`), so either 0, 1 or 2 policies should be created.

I have an issue with below code. Error message is:

> Error: Unsupported block type...
> in data "aws_iam_policy_document" "s3_logging_service":
> |  13:     dynamic "s3_logging_policy" {
> |
> | Blocks of type "s3_logging_policy" are not expected here.

Code:

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "s3_logging_service" {

  statement {
    actions = [
      "s3:PutObject"
    ]
    effect = "Allow"

    dynamic "s3_logging_policy" {
      for_each = var.s3_logging_enabled == true ? [1] : []

      content {
        sid = "AllowAwsS3LoggingService"
        resources = [
          local.bucket_arn,
        ]
        principals {
          type        = "Service"
          identifiers = ["logging.s3.amazonaws.com"]
        }
      }
    }

    dynamic "elb_logging_policy" {
      for_each = var.elb_logging_enabled ? [1] : []

      sid = "EnableELBLogging"
      resources = [
        local.bucket_arn,
      ]
      principals {
        type        = "AWS"
        identifiers = ["arn:aws:iam::${local.elb_account_id}:root"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The structure of a `dynamic` block is that the name needs to match the name of the block it should output. The only valid name therefore in this case is `dynamic "statement" { ... }`. And then you need to specify a `content` which you are completely lacking at least in the second block. You need to re-study the syntax of those `dynamic` block statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each [`dynamic` block](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks) has to have the `for_each` along with the `content` block. Otherwise, the code will not work. Additionally, the `dynamic` keyword has to be followed by the name of the block argument. So, for example, the data source for creating IAM policies knows nothing about `s3_logging_policy` (nor `elb_logging_policy`). It has only blocks of `statement` argument. That means you cannot use `dynamic` blocks that way. To fix this, you need to use the following:

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "s3_logging_service" {

  dynamic "statement" {
    for_each = var.s3_logging_enabled == true ? [1] : []
    content {
      actions = [
        "s3:PutObject"
      ]
      effect = "Allow"
      sid    = "AllowAwsS3LoggingService"
      resources = [
        local.bucket_arn,
      ]
      principals {
        type        = "Service"
        identifiers = ["logging.s3.amazonaws.com"]
      }
    }
  }

  dynamic "statement" {
    for_each = var.elb_logging_enabled ? [1] : []
    content {
      sid = "EnableELBLogging"
      effect = "Allow"
      actions = [
        "s3:PutObject"
      ]
      resources = [
        local.bucket_arn
      ]
      principals {
        type        = "AWS"
        identifiers = ["arn:aws:iam::${local.elb_account_id}:root"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: just one remark to the 2nd dynamic bloc: actions and effect missing. Besides that works well. Thank you for your explanation!!!

Comment: That's true, fixed!