# Conditionally adding statement to aws_iam_policy

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have the following terraform script that tries to conditionally add second statement

```
variable "s3_buckets" {
  type = list(string)
  description = "list of s3 buckets"    
}

variable "kms_key_arns" {
  type = list(string)
  description = "List of  the ARNs of KMS keys"
  default = []
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "aws_iam_policy_s3" {
  name = "s3_policy"
  
  policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
    
    Statement = [
      {
        Effect = "Allow"
        Action = [
          "s3:GetObject",
          "s3:ListBucket"
        ]
        Resource = var.s3_buckets
      },
      
      dynamic "second_statement" {
        for_each = length(var.kms_key_arns) > 0 ? [1] : []
        
        content {
          Effect = "Allow"
          Action = [
            "kms:Encrypt",
            "kms:Decrypt",
            "kms:ReEncrypt*",
            "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
            "kms:DescribeKey"
          ]
          Resource = var.kms_key_arns
        }
      }
    ]
  })
}
```

However this throws error

```
Error: Missing item separator
│

│   on ..\..\..\..\modules\lambda\main.tf line 59, in resource "aws_iam_policy" "aws_iam_policy_s3":
│   49:     Statement = [
│   50:       {
│   51:         Effect = "Allow"
│   52:         Action = [
│   53:           "s3:GetObject",
│   54:           "s3:ListBucket"
│   55:         ]
│   56:         Resource = var.s3_buckets
│   57:       },
│   58:
│   59:       dynamic "statement" {
│
│ Expected a comma to mark the beginning of the next item.
```

Not sure where I am missing the separator. I am using

Terraform v1.5.5
on windows_386
provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws v5.12.0

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76786871/conditional-creation-of-policy-in-aws-iam-policy-document-resource-with-dynamic/76786936#76786936?

Answer (score 2):

The `jsonencode` function would not accept a Terraform block within its input parameters, but rather only HCL2 types. Also you would want a `map` type here for the element of the `list` anyway instead of a nested block as an AWS IAM policy would not be able to transform/serialize from a Terraform block. We can accomplish this with the `concat` function and a ternary to append a `map` element to the list that either contains a structure, or is an empty `list` constructor:

```
policy = jsonencode({
  Version = "2012-10-17"

  Statement = concat([
  {
    Effect = "Allow"
    Action = [
      "s3:GetObject",
      "s3:ListBucket"
    ]
    Resource = var.s3_buckets
  }]),
  length(var.kms_key_arns) > 0 ? [{
      Effect = "Allow"
      Action = [
        "kms:Encrypt",
        "kms:Decrypt",
        "kms:ReEncrypt*",
        "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
        "kms:DescribeKey"
      ]
      Resource = var.kms_key_arns
    }
  }], [])
})
```

The `concat` returns a `list(map)` with either one or two elements depending upon the ternary utilizing the conditional returning the logical specified in the question, and therefore dynamically transforms to a JSON string as desired for the AWS IAM policy.

Answer (score 1):

You can't place `dynamic` blocks inside `jsonencode()`. If you want to use `dynamic` blocks, I suggest using the `aws_iam_policy_document` data source to create the IAM policy, which would look like this:

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "aws_iam_policy_s3" {
  statement {
    effect = "Allow"

    actions = [
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:ListBucket",
    ]

    resources = [
      var.s3_buckets
    ]
  }

  dynamic "statement" {
    for_each = length(var.kms_key_arns) > 0 ? [1] : []
        
    content {
      effect = "Allow"
      actions = [
        "kms:Encrypt",
        "kms:Decrypt",
        "kms:ReEncrypt*",
        "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
        "kms:DescribeKey"
      ]
      resources = [ var.kms_key_arns ]
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "aws_iam_policy_s3" {
  name   = "s3_policy"
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.aws_iam_policy_s3.json
}
```